# Compactness of the set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Can anyone explain me is this set compact or not?
$$S:=\{x ∈ \mathbb{R} : x ∈ (2, 3] ∪ (4, 5]\text{ or } x=10\}$$
I already know that for instance $(2,3]$ and $(4,5]$ are not compact, but does it imply for the union?

Comment: The union of non-compact sets can be compact, take for instance $[0, \frac 3 4)\cup(\frac 1 4, 1]$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in $\Bbb R$, a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded, $S=(2,3]\cup (4,5]\cup \{10\}$ in this case is not closed, since $2$ as a limit point is not in $S$.

(**RECALL**: $S$ is [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set) if the set of all limit point is a subset of $S$)

Answer (score 2):

Asuume that $S$ is compact. Then $(2,3]$ is compact as a closed subset of $S$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $S$ is compact. Then $S$ isclosed, but $S$ does not contain the limit points 2 and 4, a contradiction.

Comment: That's a very convoluted and unnecessary use of contradiction. Simpler to just say "S does not contain the limit points 2 and 4, thus S is not closed, thus it's not compact."

Answer (score 1):

The open cover $\{U_n : n = 1,2,\cdots\}$ has no finite subcover, where
$$
U_n = S \cap \left(2+\frac{1}{n},\infty\right) .
$$